# World Space canvas rendering in front of line mesh

Tags: unity, rendering, htc-vive

I'm attempting to attach a pointer to my steamvr controller to simplify world interactions. I'm very new to unity, but found a nice volumetric line asset (VolumetricLines) that aesthetically is exactly what I want. However, it seems to be rendering behind my canvas, as you can see here: 
[image: Rendering Problem]

The canvas is set to world space with the event camera set to the VR camera, and renders properly for all world objects except this line. The line also renders properly with all objects except this canvas.

What exactly is the mechanic that causes the line to render behind the canvas, when it renders in front of other game objects, and what could I do to fix the render order?

Comment: Does changing the order in layer on the Canvas to -1 help at all ?

Comment: Perfect! Setting the Sort layer to Default and the "order in layer" to -1 works.

Comment: Glad you tested it out. I made a answer so that people could find the solution easily.

Comment: Because you answered exactly the question I asked, I'm setting your answer as the correct one, and will ask a new question if necessary. However, do you know why now, the entire line renders in front of the canvas (even the part that's physically behind it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order in layer on the canvas to -1.